# Service Fabric: pkg\Debug is not found

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

I have created Service Fabric Application and added Stateless ASP.NET Core Web API 3.1 project into it. When I run the Service Fabric Application locally using VS 2019, I am getting the below error:-

```
The PowerShell script failed to execute. See the Service Fabric Tools pane in the output window for details.
```

Bellow is the output window info

```
C:\Users\malle\Documents\Mahesh\Projects\RetentionPortal\API\Application1\pkg\Debug is not found.
At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service 
Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication.ps1:120 char:9
+         throw $errMsg
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (C:\Users\malle\...g is not found.:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : C:\Users\malle\Documents\Mahesh\Projects\RetentionPortal\API\Application1\pkg\Debug is n 
   ot found.
 
Finished executing script 'Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication'.
Time elapsed: 00:00:01.7629461
Started executing script 'Unpublish-ServiceFabricApplication'.
powershell -NonInteractive -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "[void](Connect-ServiceFabricCluster); Import-Module 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\ServiceFabricSDK.psm1'; Unpublish-ServiceFabricApplication -ApplicationName 'fabric:/Application1' -ErrorAction Stop"
Removing application...
Finished executing script 'Unpublish-ServiceFabricApplication'.
Time elapsed: 00:00:01.5278716
Started executing script 'UnregisterApplicationType'.
powershell -NonInteractive -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "[void](Connect-ServiceFabricCluster); Import-Module 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\ServiceFabricSDK.psm1'; if (Get-ServiceFabricApplicationType -ApplicationTypeName 'Application1Type' | Where-Object { $_.ApplicationTypeVersion -eq '1.0.0' }) { Unregister-ServiceFabricApplicationType -ApplicationTypeName 'Application1Type' -ApplicationTypeVersion '1.0.0' -ErrorAction Stop -Force }"
Finished executing script 'UnregisterApplicationType'.
Time elapsed: 00:00:01.4425472
```

Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## General solution steps:

1. Reboot Computer
2. Log On
3. Start Visual Studio as Admin
4. Open Service Fabric Project
5. F5 to Debug
6. Try to run the same project again, same output
7. Run POwerShell as Admin,  `Connect-ServiceFabricCluster`.

[image]

8. Start debugging (F5) in Visual Studio
9. Everything's fine now

For more details, you can check the issues oin github.

[Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication fails to read ApplicationManifest.xml](https://github.com/microsoft/service-fabric-issues/issues/812)

## If the above solution does not work, it is recommended to try the following steps.

1. Create `pkg/Debug` folder.

[image]

2. I have some files under Debug folder, so I deleted them.

[image]

3. Clean and Rebuild Solution.

[image]

4. F5 Run. It will generate files you want.

[image]